# Do I need to put a comma? Why?

Tags: словоупотребление, пунктуация

For example, I have two sentenses:

> Поскуливающая собака лежащая в углу лениво переводила свой взгляд то на хозяев, то на кость.

and

> Лежащая в углу поскуливающая собака лениво переводила свой взгляд то на хозяев, то на кость.

Where do I have to put commas and where don't? Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Поскуливающая собака, *лежащая в углу*, лениво переводила свой взгляд то на хозяев, то на кость.

We usually put commas before and after the reduced participle clause (причастный оборот) when it follows the noun which it determines.

> *Лежащая в углу* поскуливающая собака лениво переводила свой взгляд то на хозяев, то на кость.

We don't put commas when the reduced participle clause comes before the noun which it determines.

**But** if the reduced participle clause has the meaning of a condition or a reason or refers to a **pronoun**, we put commas.

> Потревоженная громким стуком в дверь, девочка вскочила с кровати. (reason )
>
> Не умеющий стрелять, брат, конечно же, в очередной раз промахнулся. (reason)
>
> Изможденный жарой, **он** жадно припал к студеной колодезной воде. (pronoun)
>
> Утомленная бессонной ночью, **она** уснула перед рассветом. (pronoun)